# passing values to a Modal UIViewController - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, modalviewcontroller

I have a list of user profiles in a UICollectionView and when I tap on one of the users, I have a segue that Modally shows the users profile however I can't seem to pass the values from one View to another. Eg.. Image data, Username, etc.

On my UICollectionViewController I have the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showSelectedUserProfile" {

        let cell = sender as! GrafterCell
        let SP = segue.destinationViewController as! SelectedProfileViewController
        let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell)

        var username = allUsernames[indexPath!.row]
        SP.username.text = username

    }
}
```

`cell` is the cell from the collection view, SP if the destination view controller

When I run the script I get the following error

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

it shows that `SP.username` is nil and I don't know why it is nil as it's connected to the Class and called `username`

```
class SelectedProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnHideSelectedProfileViewController: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var userProfilePicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}

@IBAction func btnHideSelectedProfileViewControllerClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of objects with a property `username` with a property `text`. From that I gather that you are perhaps storing an array of objects where the `username` property is a `UILabel`?

This would be very bad design. Your data array should just have data objects, not UI elements. Never use the content of UI elements to store and retrieve data (which is what you seem to be doing). UI elements should be used only to display data.

You need to give your destination controller a property of type `String` to hold the username information.

Also, don't call a label `username` which is misleading. If its a label, call it `nameLabel` to make the code readable and intelligible to an outside reader.

Comment: hi, i have changed it to `usernameLabel` and the `var username = allUsernames[indexPath!.row]` is returning a string when i print the value and it returns the username of the selected user. it's the `SP.usernameLabel.text` that is showing as `nil`

Comment: You are still using UI to store data, in this case to pass it to the controller. The label is not even created during `prepareForSegue`, so the text assignment has no effect. Use a string property of the destination controller to hold this data.